# Php, SQL not working

Tags: php, html, sql, database

So lately I've tried my attempt at SQL, and PHP, and other such, I've come to a problem that of which being: INSERT INTO, just can't seem to work for me. Here's what I have in the PHP file:

```
   $sql = "INSERT INTO forum(USERID, FN, LN, Email) VALUES (NULL,'".$_POST['FN']."', '".$_POST['LN']."', '".$_POST['Email']."';";
```

This string works, however, I get This error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Would anyone be able to provide info on this?

Comment: you have missed closing bracket ")"

Answer (score 3):

You must close the parenthesis:

```
   $sql = "INSERT INTO forum(USERID, FN, LN, Email) VALUES (NULL,'".$_POST['FN']."', '".$_POST['LN']."', '".$_POST['Email']."');";
```

Comment: And please read http://docs.php.net/security.database.sql-injection